# point-to-site vpn connections not changing public ip - azure vnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, azure, virtual-network

I have an azure hosted sql server, for development reasons, I have added the ip address of my VPN to the firewall settings, so I can connect when I am at home etc.

I have setup an azure virtual network with a gateway and setup a point-to-site connection as detailled [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Having connected to the gateway, ipconfig shows a section `PPP adaptor myNewNetwork`, with the VNets public IP address. However, when connected I tried visiting `http://www.whatsmyip.org/`, and it shows my routers IP address (the same IP as before connecting to the VPN). I have also tried connecting to my Database and that failed too.

Have I misunderstood what the SSTP VPN does, or is there some additional configuration required to route traffic through the VNet's public IP.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when connected I tried visiting http://www.whatsmyip.org/,
>   and it shows my routers IP address

Based on my knowledge, it is a design behavior. When you create a Point-to-Site VPN, the traffic transfer to Internet will continue use your ISP network, the traffic will not go to Azure VNet. So, you only get your ISP public IP address.

> I have also tried connecting to my Database and that failed too.

Do your database on Azure Virtual Network? Please ensure your database and your vpn gateway in the same VNet. You could test  database in your lab. `telnet <database private ip> port`.

Comment: I see, is there a way to route traffic through the VNet's public IP?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards You should use forced tunneling, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-forced-tunneling-rm).

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Hi, your database is Paas service on a database on Azure VM?

Comment: Yes it is a Paas hosted offering

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Now, Paas SQL server could not integrated into Azure VNet.

Comment: Yes I know. I am only really trying to be able to change my PC's public IP address to something reliable that I can program into the SQL Server's firewall

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards According to your scenario, maybe you could create a Azure VM with static Public IP. VPN could not achieve your scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63784/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-george-edwards).

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards 
According to your scenario, I think you have two solution. 
1.Create a VM with static Public IP 2.Use VPN with forced tunneling. But I think create VM is a more suitable option.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Hi, do you solve this issue? Please let me know if you want to more future help.

Comment: How does Forced Tunneling work?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards You could refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-forced-tunneling-rm).